# React useState not change value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, axios

I use `useState` like this and onclick event with name genreHandler:

```js
    const [clickedGenre, setClickedGenre] = useState<string>(null)

    const genreHandler= (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLLIElement>) => {
      console.log(clickedGenre)
      const li: HTMLLIElement = event.currentTarget;
      setClickedGenre(li.id);    
      axios.get(API_URL+"products?category.genre="+clickedGenre)
        .then((response) => {
          setProductList( response.data );
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
          console.log(error)
        }),[clickedGenre]
      }
```

here's my li tag

```html
    <li className="list-group-item text-uppercase" 
      key= {category.id} id={category.genre} 
      onClick={genreHandler}>{category.genre}</li>
```

When I click on li the usestate (clickedGenre) still null not change to {category.genre}. It's change on double click. Please help me, what's wrong with my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this part of your code

```
  setClickedGenre(li.id);    
  axios.get(API_URL+"products?category.genre="+clickedGenre)
```

React is asynchronous, so `clickedGenre` will not have the updated value yet when used at `axios`, so that's why it is OK the second time (after the asynchronous update).

So the correct code would be to use directly the `li.id` value

```
  setClickedGenre(li.id);    
  axios.get(API_URL+"products?category.genre=" + li.id)
```